# Adding swipe recognizer to the second view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a nib file with two view (portrait and landscape). I have added swipe recognizer to it. But the swipe is not being recognized in landscape view, it works fine in portrait view. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: How are you setting them up - the views and gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have added the same gesture in two views  **so try** adding two different gesture in two views , **because** A gesture could have one view to attach with **but** a view could have multiple gesture attach to with.